# error 10060 at work computer when using google places api

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, google-api

i have the error that has been listed on many websites but there is no correct answer too.
i am trying to use google API to get the address of a business using place id.
it gives thr error 10060 as the server did not respond in time..
how to resolve this?

Comment: Does your company have any network proxies in place?

Comment: how can i check that?

Comment: so i just checked yes, there is something in use automatic script column